# how to create simple pagination in php, using mysql database

Tags: php

```
 <?php 
 include 'connections.php';
 $search = $_POST['searchvalue']; // search value is getting from HTML FORM i.e user entered value
 if(strlen($search)>=1)
   else{
 echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
 $search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);
 $x = "";
 $construct = "";  
 foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
 {
 $x++;
 if($x==1)
 $construct .="title LIKE '%$search_each%'";
 else
 $construct .="AND title LIKE '%$search_each%'";
 } 
 $construct ="SELECT * FROM books WHERE $construct";
 $run = mysql_query($construct);
 $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
 if ($foundnum!=0)
 while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
 {
 echo $result; // i have more code to print the result instead i am just using '$result' here.....
 }
 }
 }
 ?>
```

above is code for showing searching result I am successfully showing results in my page but I want to show only three results per page. I want to develop pagination for this, I searched logic for pagination in stackoverflow and google, but I go sick on that code I am feeling more complicated I am not at all understanding the pagination logic. please anyone help me how do I develop pagination in simple way?? and I am not expert in php, I am just beginner... thanks in advance..

Comment: This code is broken, there appears to be a bit missing.

Comment: What is the error you facing while you trying your code ?